# Pre-load CursorAdapter views

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to fill a list. I am recycling my views and using a `ViewHolder` to get fast loading, but the problem is that there is an image in every view that needs to be downloaded.. The view is a lot like your typical facebook feed. Even though I only need a very low resolution image, it still takes a while to load it, obviously.. And during this time, the recycled view's image is displayed, which I really do not like.

My question is, is there a way of pre-loading views in any way? The list is pretty big, so I really do not want to download and cache all of the images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this library: https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader It allows you to lazy load your images and support caching and other cool stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ImageLoader](http://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader)! It makes it easy to download, display and cache remote images.